# React-native Image URL loaded from REST API not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My app fetches latest posts from a Wordpress backend and populates a Listview with the text components an Image component. The Image component URI points to a function called fetchimageurl(id)

```
<Image 
    source={{uri: this.fetchimageurl(post.featured_media)}}
    style={{width: 400, height: 400}}
/>
```

The function fetchimageurl(id) takes the id value of the post object and hits the backend API/Media endpoint with the specific post ID to return the thumbnail URL.

```
fetchimageurl(id){
    fetch('http://ipaddress/sitename/wp-json/wp/v2/media/'+id)
    .then(function(response){
        if (!response.ok){
            console.log("Rewrite error handling - Draft code")
            return
        }
        response.json().then(function(data){
            return data.media_details.sizes.medium_large.source_url
        })
    })
}
```

The fetch method is working fine and is parsing and returning the URL correctly, however, the Image component fails to display the image once the parsed URL is passed back.

I am guessing the issue has to do with RN rendering the component prior to having the URLs returned by the function or something of that sort. I could not find much in the docs related to the life cycle of the image component. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Which platform are you using (ios / android)? Does the image url have HTTPS?

Comment: Same opinion with above comment. In case ios you can follow this tutorial https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Comment: @RafaelMotta I am developing for Android. However, HTTPS is not the issue in this case as I have tested hard-coded URIs of both HTTP and HTTPS and they both worked when statically set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't pass a Promise to `uri`.

Somewhere in your Component invoke the Promise and then set resulting URI in component's state:

```
this.fetchimageurl(post.featured_media).then(res => {
  this.setState({imageUri: res})
})
```

Then in render:

```
<Image 
    source={{uri: this.state.imageUri}}
    style={{width: 400, height: 400}}
/>
```

Comment: Yop that's the normal way to do it though don't forget to add the catch

Comment: This Answer Help me to fetch image fusing a URL. style={{width: 400, height: 400}} are need to display. Thank you